# asynchronous Methods and Entity Framework

Tags: .net, entity-framework, api, asynchronous

Community. Thanks for Reading my Post.
Im with some problems with an api in .Net.
This API have 3 Services. "PushNotifications","Register","PushNotificationRegistration

- PushNotifications: This Service, avoid me to Send Push to all Devices Previous register.
- Register: This is the New Register Service.
- PushNotificationRegistration: This is the Old service of the Old API. Its is here to coexist while others Applications isnt Updated.

[image: Diagrama Estructura]

**Class's:**

```
public class Subscription
{

    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string ClientId { get; set; }
    [StringLength(1000)]
    public string Token { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime LastUpdateDate { get; set; }
    public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }
    [Index("IX_Device_App", 2, IsUnique = true)]
    [ForeignKey("device")]
    public string DeviceId { get; set; }
    public virtual Device device { get; set; }
    [Index("IX_Device_App", 1, IsUnique = true)]
    [ForeignKey("app")]
    public int AppId { get; set; }
    public virtual App app { get; set; }
}

public class App
{
    public App()
    {
        this.Subscriptions = new HashSet<Subscription>();
    }
    [Key]
    public int AppId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [JsonIgnore]
    public virtual ICollection<Subscription> Subscriptions { get; set; }
}
public class Device
{
    public Device()
    {
        this.Subscriptions = new HashSet<Subscription>();
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// De esta forma utilizo una Key String
    /// </summary>
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    [Index(IsUnique = true)]
    [Column(TypeName = "nvarchar")]
    [StringLength(200)]
    public string DeviceId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime LastUpdateDate { get; set; }
    [JsonIgnore]
    public virtual ICollection<Subscription> Subscriptions { get; set; }
}
```

**Methods Sign**

```
public async  Task<Crosslayer.GenericReturnValue> Register(Crosslayer.Entities.Dtos.SubscriptionDto request)
public  async Task<Crosslayer.GenericReturnValue> PushNotificationRegistration(Crosslayer.Entities.Olds.Subscriptions subscription)
```

All Methods are Asyncronus. I have two Problems:

**1)**
At the moment of find a Subscription, I got full Data of Subscription and App but Sometime Device Data is not recovered. I just Added Join to the query for Fix this problem but sometime device data is not recovered. I add (if) to recover Device Data when is Null to fix for a while short time

```
Subscription DbSubscription = await (from s in context.Subscriptions
                                           join app in context.App on s.AppId equals app.AppId
                                           join dev in context.Device on s.DeviceId equals dev.DeviceId
                                           where s.DeviceId == subscription.device.DeviceId &&
                                           s.AppId == subscription.app.AppId
                                           select s).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
 foreach (var item in aux)
                    {
                        ///If for Fix Device return Null
                        if (item.device == null)
                        {
                            item.device = await (from d in context.Device
                                                 where d.DeviceId == item.DeviceId
                                                 select d).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
                        }
```

**2)**
Not every time, but sometime, i got an Exception impossible to Control it. All Methods are asynchronous and Context Caller with Await.

> System.NotSupportedException: A second operation started on this context before a previous asynchronous operation completed. Use 'await' to ensure that any asynchronous operations have completed before calling another method on this context. Any instance members are not guaranteed to be thread safe.     en System.Data.Entity.Internal.ThrowingMonitor.EnsureNotEntered()     en System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.IDbAsyncEnumerable<T>.GetAsyncEnumerator()     en System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.IDbAsyncEnumerableExtensions.ForEachAsync[T](IDbAsyncEnumerable`1 source, Action`1 action, CancellationToken cancellationToken)     en System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.IDbAsyncEnumerableExtensions.ToListAsync[T](IDbAsyncEnumerable`1 source, CancellationToken cancellationToken)     en System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.IDbAsyncEnumerableExtensions.ToListAsync[T](IDbAsyncEnumerable`1 source)     en PushNotification_NewProject.Controllers.PushNotificationController.d__8.MoveNext() en C:#########\Controllers\PushNotificationController.cs:línea 760

Answer (score 0):

Check if you are using await when you call Register or PushNotificationRegistration functions in your code.

Or give the c# code where you are using those two functions.

Comment: Register and PushNotificationRegister are Api Service called from Mobiles Applications. Understand?